# jQuery addClass to 'THIS' element

Tags: jquery, html

I tried to addclass to element on click. used addClass()  but no luck

```
jQuery(".act_nav").on("click",function(){
    var str=jQuery(this).attr('id');
    var title=jQuery(this).attr('title');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
});
```

HTML

```
 <li  id="act_about-us" class="act_nav" title="About US"><span id="ic_abt"></span><a href="about-us">About</a></li>
```

CSS

```
 .active  #ic_abt{ background-position: -37px  -448px;  }
```

Comment: Does the click handler actually get called?

Comment: yes i added alert function  its working getting id and title also

Comment: it should work, see the demo example http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/WeL5K/

Comment: If still not try making a fiddle for your problem

Comment: what does `no luck` mean exactly ?

Comment: show us your css (containing `.active`) ... and your HTML (containing your `act_nav`)

Comment: in fiddle its working but not working in my project!!!!
all other codes before and after this  working perfectly

Comment: check the console, probably syntax error somewhere else breaking the javascript.

Comment: Are you sure that the click handler code you've shown here is *the only* code?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your css.

`.active  #ic_abt{ background-position: -37px  -448px;  }`

Only works if the class is `active` and the ID is `ic_abt`. But your ID is `act_about-us`.

Comment: i checked in inspect element   no class added after click

Comment: @SebinSimon: I want to call you names